# SPARQL and Rules for ontologies

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl

Is it possible to create **if/then** rules using SPARQL and infer new relationships on my data?
For example, could I encode rules like the following?

- **if** (blood_sugar > 126 **and** blood_sugar < 500) **then** blood_sugar_level = High
- **if** (blood_sugar_level = High) **then** (service = adjust_insulin_dose)

Comment: You can insert and delete information from a graph based on what matches, so yes, you can probably do this.  However, as it is written, there's not enough information here to tell you _how_, since we don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Hi,Thank's for your respons. I prefere to use SWRL, I'm not sure that I will need to SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

The question really doesn't provide enough data to figure out exactly what you're trying to do, but you can certainly bind values based on particular conditions.  For instance, the following query includes some inline data (to associate patients with blood sugar levels), and binds the values of the variables `?bloodSugarLevel` and `?service` accordingly.

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/20840035/1281433/>

select ?patient ?service where {
  # some sample data of patients and
  # their blood sugar levels
  values (?patient ?bloodSugar) {
    (:alice 120)
    (:bill  150)
  }

  # bind ?bloodSugarLevel to :high or :low as appropriate.
  bind( if( 126 < ?bloodSugar && ?bloodSugar < 500,
            :high,
            :low )
        as ?bloodSugarLevel )

  # bind ?service to :adjust-insulin-dose if the
  # ?bloodSugarLevel is :high, else to :do-nothing.
  bind( if( ?bloodSugarLevel = :high,
            :adjust-insulin-dose,
            :do-nothing )
        as ?service )
}
```

```
----------------------------------
| patient | service              |
==================================
| :alice  | :do-nothing          |
| :bill   | :adjust-insulin-dose |
----------------------------------
```

Alternatively, you might look into [3.1.3 DELETE/INSERT](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) with which you can write an update query like the following to add triples to the graph (where the … is the same as above).

```
insert { ?patient :hasService ?service }
where { … }
```